# Spring Boot приложение не запускается

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, eclipse, spring-security

Spring Boot приложение со Spring Security перестает запускаться при добавлении в проект такого класса:

```
package com.example.demo6.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                .requestMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin((form) -> form
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
            )
            .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
             User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

До его добавления все нормально запускается, а после - перестает. В консоль выводится только часть всех надписей, которые должны выводится при полном успешном запуске. Вот вывод консоли:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.2)

2023-08-04T21:21:53.813+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [           main] com.example.demo6.Demo6Application       : Starting Demo6Application using Java 20.0.2 with PID 18804 (C:\Users\sbnet\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Проекты\demo6\demo6\demo6\target\classes started by sbnet in C:\Users\sbnet\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Проекты\demo6\demo6\demo6)
2023-08-04T21:21:53.815+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [           main] com.example.demo6.Demo6Application       : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-08-04T21:21:54.258+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-08-04T21:21:54.286+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 15 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-08-04T21:21:54.686+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-08-04T21:21:54.697+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-08-04T21:21:54.697+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.11]
2023-08-04T21:21:54.776+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-08-04T21:21:54.777+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 933 ms
2023-08-04T21:21:54.880+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-08-04T21:21:54.915+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.6.Final
2023-08-04T21:21:54.916+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2023-08-04T21:21:54.992+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [           main] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-08-04T21:21:55.093+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-08-04T21:21:55.105+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-08-04T21:21:55.229+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@7a36c83a
2023-08-04T21:21:55.230+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-08-04T21:21:55.317+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [           main] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-08-04T21:21:55.460+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-08-04T21:21:55.463+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-08-04T21:21:55.495+03:00  WARN 18804 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-08-04T21:21:55.508+03:00  WARN 18804 --- [           main] o.s.security.core.userdetails.User       : User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder() is considered unsafe for production and is only intended for sample applications.
2023-08-04T21:21:55.763+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@7cbf4f8c, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@55c46ec1, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@6da646b8, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@27ec0d06, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@e6e5da4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@2430cf17, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@2382b2f, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3a48c398, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@3dded90a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@3eff6846, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6ceb11f9, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@5d22604e]
2023-08-04T21:21:55.857+03:00  WARN 18804 --- [           main] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates, check your Thymeleaf configuration, or set spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=false)
2023-08-04T21:21:55.934+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-08-04T21:21:55.941+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [           main] com.example.demo6.Demo6Application       : Started Demo6Application in 2.365 seconds (process running for 2.58)
2023-08-04T21:26:40.498+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-08-04T21:26:40.499+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-08-04T21:26:40.500+03:00  INFO 18804 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

Делаю приложение по этому туториалу: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/
Еще добавлял перед этим вот это в `application.properties` (после этого добавления все работало):

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dogs
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
server.port=8080

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

И еще создал такой класс:

```
package com.example.demo6.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        //registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo6</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo6</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>20</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Как я говорил, все перестало запускаться после добавления класса WebSecurityConfig (самого первого класса в этом вопросе).

Comment: Все, исправил. Проблема была в устаревании метода `withDefaultPasswordEncoder()` и в аннотации `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`. Заменил часть кода на новый код по инструкции по ссылке:

Answer (score 0):

Все, исправил. Проблема была в устаревании метода `withDefaultPasswordEncoder()` и в аннотации `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`.

Заменил часть кода на новый код по инструкции по ссылке: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html (ищите `withDefaultPasswordEncoder` на странице), а именно заменил этот код :

```
UserDetails user =
             User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
```

На этот:

```
PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
 // outputs {bcrypt}$2a$10$dXJ3SW6G7P50lGmMkkmwe.20cQQubK3.HZWzG3YB1tlRy.fqvM/BG
 // remember the password that is printed out and use in the next step
 System.out.println(encoder.encode("password"));
  
 
 UserDetails user = User.withUsername("user")
     .password("{bcrypt}$2a$10$dXJ3SW6G7P50lGmMkkmwe.20cQQubK3.HZWzG3YB1tlRy.fqvM/BG")
     .roles("USER")
     .build();
```